# Can I create sheet wherein cell A1 contains an API key, and then reference that value in scripts on other sheets?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have an API Key that changes sometimes that I use in a lot of sheets, it's a complete pain to update this in all of them. Can I make a sheet where I keep the current one and update it there and reference cell A1 of Sheet 1 of that sheet, let's the sheet is called APIKEY, in scripts on other sheets? If so, how?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot understand about your current issue and your goal. I apologize for this. Can I ask you about the detail of them?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a function like this (where SPREADSHEET_ID is the ID of the Google Sheet where you stored the API KEY):

```
function getA1cellFromAnotherSS() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('SPREADSHEET_ID');
  var sh = ss.getSheetByName('APIKEY');
  var a1cellval = sh.getRange("A1").getValue();
  Logger.log(a1cellval);
}
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Do you know if there is a way to make the spreadsheet run a function every 24 hours automatically, even if I don't open it? I have a function built that can refresh the token but don't know how to do the automatic bit or if its even possible? If you do and want the extra points ill make a new question.

Comment: @WARDEN https://stackoverflow.com/a/66512621/11225291