# Is it possible to make a google script function automatically execute every 12 hours, even if you do not have the sheet open?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I would like to make a function that updates the value of cell A1 of Sheet 1 of my sheet every 12 hours. Is this possible?

Comment: Please add a brief description of your search/research efforts as is suggested in [ask].

Comment: Also please clarify what you mean by function (is a built-in function or a Google Apps Script function?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to create a [time-driven](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable#time-driven_triggers) trigger for your function.

You can either do it manually from the project's trigger menu:

[image]

or programmatically.

Assuming you want to execute `myFunction` every 12 hours, you can create a time driven trigger by executing **only** and **once** the `createTrigger` function:

```
function myFunction(){
// code here
}


// execute this only and once
function createTrigger(){
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
  .timeBased()
  .everyHours(12)
  .create();
}
```

Comment: var testval = 0

function myFunction(){
testval  = testval +1 

Logger.log(testval)

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
var sheet = ss.getSheets()[0]
var cell = sheet.getRange("A1")
cell.setValue(testval)

}

// execute this only and once
function createTrigger(){
ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
  .timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(.01)
  .create();
}

Comment: That doesnt work for me

Comment: @WARDEN see the [official documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/clock-trigger-builder#everyMinutes(Integer)) . `everyMinutes` accepts only 1 , 5 , 10 , 15 or 30 minutes. You passed 0.01. Also check the error message you are getting. It should indicate why the code didn't work. If you have any questions consider posting a new thread.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66513843/i-want-to-make-a-google-script-that-adds-1-to-a-running-total-every-minute-in-p

Comment: @ChrisBurnett if you see in my code, I pass the function name as a string: `"myFunction"`.