# I want to make a google script that adds 1 to a running total every minute, in perpetuity. Utilizing previous posts I feel I am close

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
var x = 0
Logger.log(x)

function myFunction(){
var y = x+1
Logger.log(y)
x = y
Logger.log(x)
}


// execute this only and once
function createTrigger(){
ScriptApp.newTrigger(myFunction())
  .timeBased()
  .everyMinutes(1)
  .create();
}
```

Above is my code. In my head it sets x to 0, logs that. Then function myFunction is introduced and adds 1 to x and logs it.

Then based on a tip I got this bottom text should make this happen every minute. It doesnt.

Here is the execution log:
[LOG PHOTO](https://i.stack.imgur.com/syHZX.png)

I've tried it like this too: [Like 14 difference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0Om1N.png)

Comment: remember to post photo as photo and code as snippet and use links only for external resources, please take a look on https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Did my answer show you the result what you want? Would you please tell me about it? That is also useful for me to study. If this works, other people who have the same issue with you can also base your question as a question which can be solved. If you have issues for my answer yet, I apologize. At that time, can I ask you about your current situation? I would like to study to solve your issues.

Answer (score 1):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, the variable `x = 0` is declared every run. By this, `x` is not grown. I thought that this might be the reason of your issue. In this case, how about using `Properties Service`?
- Your script of `ScriptApp.newTrigger(myFunction())` is required to be modified. `functionName` of `newTrigger(functionName)` is the string value.

When above points are reflected to your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```
function myFunction() {
  var p = PropertiesService.getScriptProperties();
  var x = p.getProperty("x");
  if (x) {
    Logger.log(Number(x))  // Value before 1 is added.
    x = Number(x) + 1;
  } else {
    x = 1;  // or x = 0;
  }
  Logger.log(x) // Value after 1 was added.
  p.setProperty("x", x);
}

// execute this only and once
function createTrigger() {
  ScriptApp.newTrigger("myFunction")
    .timeBased()
    .everyMinutes(1)
    .create();
}
```

- When `createTrigger()` is run, the time-driven trigger is installed for the function of `myFunction()`.
- When `myFunction()` is run, the value of `x` is grown by adding the number of `1`.

#### References:

- [Properties Service](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/properties)
- [newTrigger(functionName)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/script/script-app#newtriggerfunctionname)